# Is StructureMap dead?

Tags: inversion-of-control, ioc-container, structuremap

Last commit was on august 28, 2011

There are 21 open issues

There is no activity since august

I doubt to use it in my new project

What do you think about it?

Comment: Noooo... it's not dead, it's done ;-)

Comment: Have been using SM2x on countless projects without issues. SM3 is slowly getting into kickstart mode.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's not dead. Take a look at FubuMVC. Jeremy Miller is working on that project with a whole bunch of people. structure map is what they are using as their IoC container.

Comment: Seconding what Adam said and speaking as a Fubu dev, StructureMap is still supported. We've all been busy lately but Jeremy still has plans to revisit for SM 3.0 this year. Given our tight timelines for our product and the functionality we need, I think him and I are both hoping that it gets to happen sooner rather than later.

Comment: @jmarnold I sent a pull request a couple weeks ago to fix an important bug and it still hasn't been dignified with a response. I also noticed that there were 6 other pull requests waiting. I also noticed yesterday that the `structuremap.net` domain registration expired - making google's cache the only place to find documentation. Regardless, the documentation is really thin, it would be good to organize an effort to improve the documentation. That's probably more important than improving StructureMap itself.

Comment: Try sending a message on the fubumvc google group.

Answer (score 8):

See the following article from Jeremy Miller "Kicking off StructureMap 3".  Looks like this might be the year for big changes within the project.  So to answer your question, I don't think StructureMap is dead.

http://jeremydmiller.com/2012/01/11/kicking-off-structuremap-3/

Comment: And it's not 'done' either ;-)

Comment: And a year and a half later, StructureMap 3 isn't done yet.